# Grafana issue with a new datasource plugin - define is not a function

Tags: plugins, grafana, datasource, grafana-templating

I used [this documentation](https://grafana.com/developers/plugin-tools/tutorials/build-a-data-source-backend-plugin) to create a brand new backend datasource plugin for Grafana.

When I start Grafana with `docker compose up`. I define a new datasource and set it to my new plugin I got this issue :

[image: issue]

What can cause this ?

I see nothing on the browser console or the docker logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

When I ran `npm run dev` I got this message :

[image: npm run dev issue]

By creating the folder `src` in `.config/webpack` it solved the problem. The `npm run dev` command ran correctly. I can now see my plugin without any issue in Grafana.